# Google big query "required parameter missing" with ruby gem

Tags: ruby, google-bigquery

I'm using Google's [ruby api client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/) to talk to big query and I have it all set up and working, except for queries where I'm getting this error:

```
{"error"=>
  {"errors"=>
    [{"reason"=>"required",
      "domain"=>"global",
      "message"=>"Required parameter is missing"}],
   "code"=>400,
   "message"=>"Required parameter is missing"}}
```

Here is what I'm calling:

```
bq = client.discovered_api("bigquery", "v2")

resp = client.execute(
    bq.jobs.query,
    {  "projectId" => "1234",
     "query" => "SELECT count(*) FROM [api_logs.api_logs_week_28__Jul_2012] where timestamp >= 1341817200 and timestamp <= 1341903599"
    }
)
```

The frustrating part is on the [query api docs](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query), these same exact parameters work just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: It's impressive that an error message this useless is still in production five years later. Nice work google!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First- - I don't know ruby, but I do know bigquery, so I've taken a look at the ruby google drive [example](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/source/browse/drive/drive.rb?repo=samples) and tried to adapt it:

```
  result = client.execute(
    :api_method =>  bq.jobs.query,
    :body_object => { "query" => "SELECT 17" },
    :parameters => { "projectId => "1234" })
```

Essentially the projectId needs to be a parameter, and the query needs to be in the post data.